# excel vba accessing worksheets

Tags: excel, vba, userform, worksheet

I have a user that is in need of accessing the raw data in a worksheet.  We gather numbers throughout the month based on a estimate. At the end of the month the numbers need to be adjusted to the exact total amount.  The user more-or-less randomly adjusts some or all of the items until the estimate entered = the exact amount.  In other words, I can't just adjust every item by, say, 2% or $50.  The user manually goes thru the list of items and assigns adjustments.  My question is: can I send the user to the worksheet to make the adjustments and have the user return to the userform that called the worksheet?

Answer (score 0):

Say a month's end we have:

[image]

So values were entered in **A1** thru **A31**
There is a *SUM()* formula 8n **A32**

To perform the adjustment, enter the actual month value in **B32** and run this small macro:

```
Sub dural()
    Dim v1 As Long, v2 As Long, delta As Long
    v1 = Range("A32").Value
    v2 = Range("B32").Value
    If v1 = v2 Then Exit Sub
    delta = v2 - v1

    If delta > 0 Then
        For i = 1 To delta
        j = Application.WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, 31)
        Cells(j, 1).Value = Cells(j, 1).Value + 1
        Next i
    Else
        For i = 1 To -delta
            j = Application.WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, 31)
            Cells(j, 1).Value = Cells(j, 1).Value - 1
        Next i
    End If
End Sub
```

Results in:

[image]

Comment: Gary's Student:  You put a lot of work into that and I thank you.... However, your solution is still a vba solution with random allocation via a formula.  I need to let the user go in manually and adjust the ones she wants.  Is there a way to pop into the worksheet from a userform and pop back after she is finished her adjustments.